# React-Grid-Layout x,y,w,h

Tags: reactjs, grid, react-grid-layout

Good day,

I want to change the position of a react grid layout but there's one thing which I do not understand React-Grid-Layout x,y,w,h, especially the x,y part. I know that w is for width, h is for height. I have done css grid and I am not sure this React-Grid-Layout works the same as the css one.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in the documentation of [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout#grid-item-props) library, the Grid Item props *x*, *y*, *w*, *h* and also *minW*, *maxW*, *minH*, *maxH* are in **grid units** (not in pixels).
Then, what you have to do is to define the number of columns using **cols** property, the row height in pixels with **rowHeight** and the **width** in pixels of the whole grid.

So, by combining these three properties (cols, rowHeight and width) of the GridLayout component you should get a grid and you would just work with grid units always.